# Thinking in C++ template specialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, generics, stl

**Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**

**Coding standard: C++0x compatible**

I have a class template

```
template <typename T1, int I>
class A
{
    public template <typename T2> void f(T2 x);
    /*...*/
};

template <typename T1, int I>
template <typename T2>
void A<T1, I>::f(T2 x)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

and partial specialization of above class

```
template <int I>
class A<char, I>
{
    public template <typename T2> void f(T2 x);
    /*...*/
};
```

Then can I specialize member function in the partially specialized class like below?

```
template <int I>
template <>
void A<char, I>::f<double>(double x)
{
}
```

Thanks!

NB: I'm not working on it but thinking if it's applicable or not. Easy rating if you know about the rule.

Comment: `public void`? Did you actually try to compile this?

Comment: @Pubby THANKS. Any constructive idea about my question?

Comment: You still didn't try to compile... hint C++ is not C# in terms of accessibility specifications.

Comment: For some reason I recall this not being possible out-of-class. Someone else can tell you why/why not.

Comment: @Xeo hmm...what's it then? Perhaps just can't specialize member functions without its class being fully specialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid because you cannot explicitly specialize a member function without also giving fixed template arguments to any enclosing class template.

***Not C++11 compatible, but working on MSVC***

The Microsoft compiler has an extension that allows to declare explicit specializations within class templates though. Even though I have never tried it, chances are good that it will accept the following non-standard code

```
template <int I>
class A<char, I>
{
    public:
    template <typename T2> void f(T2 x);

    template<> void f<double>(double x) {

    }
    /*...*/
};
```

Update: Clang compiles this and reports

```
// clang++ -fms-extensions main1.cpp
main1.cpp:10:21: warning: explicit specialization of 'f' within class scope is a
                 Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft]

  template<> void f<double>(double x) {
                  ^
```

***C++11/C++03 compatible***

The way here is overloading instead of specialization

```
template <int I>
class A<char, I>
{
    public:
    template <typename T2> void f(T2 x);

    void f(double x) {

    }
    /*...*/
};
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for and thank you Johannes. However the inline stuff may be problematic if applied to constructor in case of the inheretance of this class right?

Comment: I suppose the inline stuff problematic (inheretence, loops) and about to accept the overloading solution.